# Irvine32 on emu8086? duplicate declaration of: LPFILETIME

Tags: assembly, irvine32, emu8086

I'm trying to execute this code. It basically just makes a reversed copy of a string into a different location.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
source BYTE " This is the source string", 0
target BYTE SIZEOF source DUP('#')  


.code
main PROC

mov esi, (OFFSET source) + (SIZEOF source) - 2
mov edi, OFFSET target
mov ecx, SIZEOF source

L1: mov al, [esi]
mov [edi], al
dec esi ; pointer to source string
inc edi ; pointer to target string
loop L1

mov esi, OFFSET target ; offset of variable
mov ebx, 1 ; byte format
mov ecx, SIZEOF target-1 ; counter
call Dumpmem

exit

main ENDP
END main
```

But I encounter this error:

> duplicate declaration of: LPFILETIME

[image]

Comment: Decide if you use use `masm` or `emu8086` and edit your tags accordingly.

Comment: My apologies. I'm using emu8086.

Comment: I don't think irvine32 is compatible with emu8086. You need to write 16 bit code.

Comment: I understand that. What application should I use should I decide to use Irvine32?

Comment: `masm` for assembling. You will also need a linker and probably a debugger.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!